# How to add a new colormap on a raster dataset?

Tags: image, matlab, tiff, colormap

I am trying to replicate some ArcGIS functionality in Matlab, specifically the [Add Colormap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009w000000) function.  The Add Colormap function in ArcGIS associates a .clr file with the TIFF image so that the image has a custom color scheme associated with the TIFF when viewed.

My TIFF images have up to 6 values (1 - 6) in unsigned 8-bit integer format. You can see from the screenshot that some of the images have only 1, 2, or 3 values, while others have 6 values--resulting in variable on-screen color rendering.

I see that Matlab has [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) functionality, however, it appears to be designed only for figures, rather than for TIFF files.  How can I associate a colormap with these TIFF images in Matlab so that when I view them (e.g. in ArcGIS), they have a custom color scheme?

[image]

Comment: If I understand well you want to save your images with a given "colormap". Am I right ?

Comment: Then have a look at `imwrite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the commenters have pointed out, the `colormap` functionality isn't actually limited to just figures. The colormap concept is really just a lookup table that maps a particular value (index) to specific color (in RGB, typically).

If you check out the documentation for [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html), you will see that you can actually specify a colormap as the second input to the function.

```
load mri
im = squeeze(D(:,:,12));

% This is an indexed image (M x N)

% Save without specifying a colormap
imwrite(im, 'nocolormap.tif')
```

[image]

Now to save with a colormap

```
imwrite(im, heat, 'colormap.tif')
```

[image]

The other alternative, is to create an RGB image within MATLAB and save this image without providing a colormap to `imwrite`. You can either create this image manually

```
% Normalize a little bit for display
im = double(im) ./ max(im(:));
output = repmat(im, [1 1 3]);   % Make the image (M x N x 3)

imwrite(output, 'rgb_grayscale.tif')
```

[image]

Or you can use the built-in functions [`gray2rgb`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gray2rgb.html) or [`ind2rgb`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) to convert an indexed image to an RGB image using a specific colormap.

```
 rgb_image = gray2rgb(im, jet);
 imwrite(rgb_image, 'rgb_jet.tif')
```

[image]

One thing that is pretty important to remember in all of this is that by default, any MATLAB colormap only has 64 colors. So if you need more colors than that, you can specify it when constructing the colormap

```
size(gray)

    64   3

size(gray(1000))

    1000   3
```

This is particularly important if you're trying to display high fidelity data.